# Parsing XML from resellerclub api

Tags: xml, api

I'm triying to parse a xml file but not working. I tried this:

```
$url = /* Some like this */'https://test.httpapi.com/api/customers/signup.xml?auth-userid=0&api-key=key&username=email@email.com&passwd=password9&name=name &company=company&address-line-1=address-line-1&city=city&state=state&country=US&zipcode=0000&phone-cc=0&phone=000000&lang-pref=en';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$status = $info['http_code'];
echo curl_error($ch);
echo '<pre>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response); 
print_r($xml);
```

and i get this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [body] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [h1] => 400 Bad request
        )

)
```

URL is correct, i can see this:

```
<response>
    <status>ERROR</status>
    <message>Required parameter missing: name</message>
</response>
```

I also tried this and get "file error" :

```
$xml = file_get_contents($url) or die ('file error');
```

or

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($url) or die ('file error');
```

or

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die ('file error');
```

How I can parse it?

Answer (score 0):

Error message:

First:

```
$xml = file_get_contents($url) or die ('1file error');

Warning: file_get_contents(myurl) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request in /myserver on line 354
```

Second:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($url) or die ('2file error');


Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /myserver on line 356

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: myurl in /myserver on line 356

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^ in /myserver on line 356
2file error
```

And third:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die ('3file error');

Warning: simplexml_load_file(myurl) [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in /myserver on line 358

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "myurl" in /myserver on line 358
3file error
```

Answer (score 0):

All request to test.httpapi need to be GET, even if they're traditionally POST.

http://manage.resellerclub.com/kb/answer/753